# Magento2: Product import is not working (Static attribute)

Tags: magento2, import, importexport, import-products

I'm trying to update some products using the import file. I Realized that one attribute is not updating. I noticed this attributes is backend_type = static. This is related to the problem or can be something else? Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Camilo, How did you create the attribute from the backend or programmatically?

Comment: Hi @Magedivine the attribute was created programmatically. I found that problem could be due static attributes has the data in catalog_product_entity table but the post was about Magento 1.9 so i'm not sure yet

Comment: Are you using the attribute code in the CSV column & assigning the value? Please confirm.

Comment: The attribute is boolean so I use Yes/No as value and the attribute code as column name. I Tested with other custom attributes and works as expected. So I guess is because the attribute is static and values are store in catalog_product_entity table

Comment: Do one thing, use the additional_attributes as column name and values will be like attribute_code=attribute_value. This should work..

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

Please use the below process to update the product attribute using import:

Create a CSV to import and add the `additional_attributes` column and then use the values like `attribute_code=attribute_value`.

**Please check the below screenshot:**

[image]

I have used `attribute_code` (this is the test text). Please replace your attribute code with `attribute_code`.

Comment: Hi @Magedivine I tjust tried this way but the custom static attribute does not update. I Also tried with other int custom attribute and worked so I'm not sure but the problem could be about the catalog_product_entity_type tables cuz static use just catalog_product_entitu table